# Retrieve all invoice activity if there is a credit record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve all rows of invoice activity, except for payments, when there is a Credit Memo.  We have a common order number that can have different activity such as Invoice (I), Credit memo (C), Payment (P), Debit Memo (D).  If an order does not have a Credit memo, I do not want it listed.

The result set I'm looking for is:

```
Order_id   record_type    amount    order_date  invoice_no_string  
-------------------------------------------------------------------  
5023318    Invoice        3063.38    3/7/16     5023318  
5023318    Credit memo    -3063.38   3/7/16     5023318  
5023318    Invoice        2723.00    3/7/16     5023318A
```

Instead, after days of trying to figure this out, I'm down to getting this:

```
Order_id   record_type    amount    order_date  invoice_no_string
-------------------------------------------------------------------
5023318    Invoice        3063.38    3/7/16     5023318
5023318    Credit memo    -3063.38   3/7/16     5023318
5023318    Credit memo    -3063.38   3/7/16     5023318
5023318    Invoice        2723.00    3/7/16     5023318A
```

I am new to SQL and not sure what database type this is...

Here is the code, any help is appreciated..

```
SELECT 
    file1.order_id order_id,
    file1.invoice_no_string,
    file1.bill_date,
    convert(varchar(10),orders.ordered_date,101) order_date,
    file1.customer_id cust_no,
    customer.name cust_name,
    file1.record_type type,
    file1.amount amount,
    file1.source

FROM 
    open_item file1
JOIN
    open_item file2
ON
    file1.order_id = file2.order_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    customer on customer.id = file1.customer_id and 
    customer.company_id = 'TMS' 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    orders on orders.id = file1.order_id and
    orders.company_id = 'TMS'
WHERE 
    file1.company_id = 'TMS' and 
    orders.ordered_date >= {d '2016-03-01'} and 
    orders.ordered_date <= {d '2016-03-15'} and
    file1.source ='B' and
    file1.record_type = 'I' and
    file2.record_type = 'C' or
    file1.company_id = 'TMS' and 
    orders.ordered_date >= {d '2016-03-01'} and 
    orders.ordered_date <= {d '2016-03-15'} and
    file1.source ='B' and
    file1.record_type = 'C' 

ORDER BY 
    order_id
```

Comment: This likely won't fix your problem, but you are converting your `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s into `INNER JOIN`s by including the right-hand table filters  (`orders`) in the `WHERE` clause.  Those should be moved to the `ON` clause.

Comment: If your query runs, then it is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems overcomplicated for what you want to do.  With all the different tables in the `FROM` clause, I am not clear on the exactly filtering you are looking for.

But, if you want all non-payment open items from customers with no credit record, then you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM open_item ot JOIN 
     customer c
     ON c.id = ot.customer_id and 
        c.company_id = 'TMS' JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.id = ot.order_id
WHERE o.ordered_date >= {d '2016-03-01'} AND 
      o.ordered_date <= {d '2016-03-15'} AND
      ot.record_type <> 'P' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM order_type ot2
              WHERE ot2.customer_id = ot.customer_id AND
                    ot2.record_type = 'C'
             );
```

Apart from the simplification, the key idea is to use `EXISTS` to see of a corresponding credit record exists for the same customer.

Comment: Thanks, the relevant data I have is basically..
    order_id    amount   record_type   source  
    1                100        I  (invoice)      B (billing)
    1                 -100      C (credit)       B
    1                 80         I                      B
     2                200       I                      B
     2                -5          C                    C (cash receipts)

I would only want order#1 from the data to be retrieved because it has an invoice and credit from source B and not source C.

I'm missing something to exclude the row if type is C and source is C

Comment: Seems like I'm limited to only 500 or so characters so I can't post the new code